# How can I automatically add random description to posts with empty content posted to WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I would like to automate the process of adding descriptions for articles published on my site. I would like to automatically insert a random description from a list of pre-edited (Advanced Custom Fields) descriptions when a new post is published **as draft**.
eg: "description_1" or "description_2" or "description_100" (randomly)

I have this code, which seems to do the trick, but I still have to insert the parameter to randomize the choice of description (randomly choose a number between 1 and 100 just after the word "description") on the line:
// Custom post content
$content = . $description_1 . ;
of this code above.
I would also like to add these two little conditions:

- The content of the article is empty
- The status of the article is set to "draft"
  Thanks for any response!

````
function show_update_postdata( $value, $post_id, $field ) {

        // Get values from POST
        $description_1 = $_POST['acf']['field_5dd00e0582125'];
        $description_2 = $_POST['acf']['field_5dd00e0582125'];
        $description_50 = $_POST['acf']['field_5dd00e0582125'];
        $description_100 = $_POST['acf']['field_5dd00e0582125'];

        // Custom post content
        $content = . $description_1 . ;
        $postdata = array(
             'ID'          => $post_id,
             'post_content'  => $content,
             'post_type'   => 'post',
        );

        wp_update_post( $postdata );
        return $value;

}
add_filter('acf/update_value/name=description_1', 'show_update_postdata', 10, 3);
add_filter('acf/update_value/name=description_2', 'show_update_postdata', 10, 3);
add_filter('acf/update_value/name=description_50', 'show_update_postdata', 10, 3);
add_filter('acf/update_value/name=description_100', 'show_update_postdata', 10, 3);```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two fucntion fisrt for content [get_post_field()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_field/) and the second is for check post status [get_post_status()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_status/). check below code.

```
function show_update_postdata( $value, $post_id, $field ) {

    $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_post_field( 'post_content', $post_id ) );

    if( $content == '' && get_post_status( $post_id ) == 'draft' ){

        // Get values from POST
        $description_1 = $_POST['acf']['field_5dd00e0582125'];
        $description_2 = $_POST['acf']['field_5dd00e0582125'];
        $description_50 = $_POST['acf']['field_5dd00e0582125'];
        $description_100 = $_POST['acf']['field_5dd00e0582125'];

        $random_content = array( $description_1, $description_2, $description_50, $description_100 );
        $random_content = $random_content[ array_rand( $random_content ) ];

        $postdata = array(
             'ID'            => $post_id,
             'post_content'  => $random_content,
             'post_type'     => 'post',
        );

        wp_update_post( $postdata );
    }
    
    return $value;


}
add_filter('acf/update_value/name=description_1', 'show_update_postdata', 10, 3);
add_filter('acf/update_value/name=description_2', 'show_update_postdata', 10, 3);
add_filter('acf/update_value/name=description_50', 'show_update_postdata', 10, 3);
add_filter('acf/update_value/name=description_100', 'show_update_postdata', 10, 3);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I edited my question to correct the imperfections that were in the code. Could you therefore see yours again? Also, I don't know if you took into account the random parameter that I especially want to insert, thank you !

Comment: Clearly, I especially want to define randomly a description among the custom fields "description_1" or "description_2" .... up to "description_100" of my article.

Comment: Thanks, I saw the fixes to your code. But, I still don't see which line of code the random choice parameter was inserted into. I also saw the conditions inserted:- The content of the article is empty
- The status of the article is set to "draft"